# Saving API response data as an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, json, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an html file with some JavaScript inside. I also have a URL that when opened is just a page that contains data from an AWS lambda API call that I received from making a lambda API using AWS API Gateway. The page looks like a completely blank page when it loads with data laid out similar to,

```
[
{"user": "bob", "groups": ["bobsGroup"], "policies": ["bobsPolicy", "anotherPolicy"["Policy3"]]},
{"user": "sal", "groups": ["salsGroup"], "policies": ["salssPolicy", "anotherPolicy"["Policy3"]]}
]
```

My question is that I am wanting to take the data from the API response and save it into an HTML paragraph element. I don't think I'm currently using the right logic or doing it in an incorrect way by trying to, inside my script tags, run the following,

```
var myjson;
$.getJSON("https://myapi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapi//myapiresource", function(json){myjson = json;});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myjson
```

where `demo` is just a paragraph tag inside my HTML

Full code snippet is,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


  </head>
  <body>


  <div id = "demo"></div>




    <script>

        var myjson;
$.getJSON("https://myapi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapi//myapiresource", function(json){ 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = json;
});


    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` inside ajax success callback...

```
var myjson;
$.getJSON("https://myapi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapi//myapiresource", function(json){
  myjson = json; 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myjson;
});
```

**Code Cleanup version**

```
$.getJSON("https://myapi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapi//myapiresource", function(json){ 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = json;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am very new to working with JavaScript and Hadn't even known what AJAX was for. I'm looking into working with it now to get a better understanding.

Comment: You're welcome! Accept this answer and upvote it if this was helpful.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that if I just take the above code that's in "code Cleanup version" and paste it into the script tag of my HTML it should populate my HTML page when opened with the data from $.getJSON?

Comment: Yes it should... after successful AJAX response, data will be  populated immediately.

Comment: So when I open my HTML page "index.html" I just get a blank screen when I thought I'd see the API response data. Do you see where the issue might be? I went ahead and edited my post to contain more details. Thanks again